# Passing a class to a form field in Django to trigger Jquery

Tags: django, forms

I have this form. I want to trigger a Jquery event when someone clicks on the dia_de_entrega field.

```
class RepartoForm(forms.Form):
    productos = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Producto.objects.none())
    nodos = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Nodo.objects.none())
    dia_de_entrega = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}))



    def __init__(self, *args, productor_pk=None, **kwargs):
        super(forms.Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if productor_pk is not None:
            self.fields['productos'].queryset = Producto.objects.filter(productor=productor_pk)
            self.fields['nodos'].queryset = Nodo.objects.exclude(productores_kickeados = productor_pk)
            self.fields['dia_de_entrega'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'datepicker'})
```

This is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Crea un reparto nuevo</title>
    <link rel=”stylesheet” href=”//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css”>
    <link rel=”stylesheet” href=”/resources/demos/style.css”>
    <script src=”https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js”></script>
    <script src=”https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js”></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="Enviar">Enviar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".datepicker").click(function(){
            alert("adasd");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it. I searched online and it seems right

Comment: What happens when you use this code? Does it work? Apart from using the wrong class in `super()`, this all seems fine.

Comment: Yeah, the code works. But Jquery doesn't, there is no alert

Comment: 2 questions: When you debug the html in your browser (right click on element + inspect element), does the element actually have the class present on it? Have you tried something like `...widget.attrs.update({'onclick': 'somefunction();'})` and defining the somefunction() function in your js?

Comment: good point. i checked and the class was indeed datepicker. it turned out the jquery references were wrong. thanks!